# How to solve the "/bin/bash: line 119: 28 Segmentation fault 'git' "clean" "-ffdx"" problem?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I need help please :)
So, 2 days I can't figure out the error.

Error: `/bin/bash: line 119: 28 Segmentation fault    'git' "clean" "-ffdx""`

I want to create a pipeline for Gitlab CI to build, test and deploy my application to CI. But when I push the checked configuration to the git repository, the CI can either follow the steps or crash and throw the error I wrote about above.
I don't know how it works. This is magic? :D

If someone has encountered this problem or knows how to solve it, I will be very happy if you share the solution.

**gitlab-ci.yaml**

```
image: mhart/alpine-node:12

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  NODE_MODULES_DIR: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules'

.npm_dependencies:
  cache:
    key: npm-deps
    paths:
      - ${NODE_MODULES_DIR}
  before_script:
    - npm ci

jest-tests:
  extends: .npm_dependencies
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run jest:test

cypress-tests:
  stage: test
  extends: .npm_dependencies
  image: cypress/browsers:node12.18.0-chrome83-ff77
  script:
    - npm install -g wait-on
    - npm run start & wait-on http://localhost:3000
    - npm run cypress:run

build:
  extends: .npm_dependencies
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
  script:
    - npm run build
```

**Detailed error and Graph CI**

[image: Error]

[image: Graph CI]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, to build a proper [mre], you're going to _need_ to do some work to break down the moving parts, so you can construct only the shortest/simplest possible reproducer for the bug in question.

Comment: Also, the error should be provided **as text**. It's much more important to be able to copy-and-paste or search it (or have it rendered in a color scheme or font size that works for the viewer) than to see the original color highlighting. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) for an in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error message indicates that `git clean` itself is crashing.

Since `git clean` is pretty reliable, you're going to need to isolate this some more—or, perhaps, just update the version of Git you're using, if that's possible.  (The bug, whatever it is, may be fixed in a newer version of Git.)

If it happens in any particular supported version of Git, and if you can isolate the problem to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can send that MRE/MCVE to the Git folks, who will track down the bug and fix it.  The isolation process might show that it's in an unsupported version of Git, though, or that it's in something outside Git proper such as a shared library.  These are still useful—they may allow you to avoid the problem—but probably won't get a fix from the Git folks.